# Dynamically change the orientation of a page in Word using C#

Tags: c#-4.0

i have to get different images from database and insert into a word document,but each image has to be placed inside the word document depending on the orientation of the word s page.

i.e
for every process i have to insert images into the same page of the word document,so i need to dynamically change the orientation of that particular page depending on the image being inserted.

Please let me know how can i dynamically change orientation of one particaular page in word using C#

Comment: I take it you are using the office InterOp assemblies?

Comment: Yes..i am...using the below code im able to change the orientation for the whole word document...but i need oly few pages orientation to be changed..objWordDoc.PageSetup.Orientation = WdOrientation.wdOrientLandscape;

Comment: ah ok - not sure then in that case - I'd only be trawling the API documentation on MSDN. From a quick glance though it might be the Sections property of the document object that represents pages? Thats just a guess, but given that Section has a PageSetup property it's a reasonable one... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.sections(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply landscape **only** to the current page, I used this:

```
Range newRange = _WordDoc.Range(CurrentDocumentPosition, CurrentDocumentPosition);
newRange.InsertBreak(WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakNextPage);
_WordDoc.Sections[_WordDoc.Sections.Count].PageSetup.Orientation = WdOrientation.wdOrientLandscape;
```

It is important to apply break of type **wdSectionBreakNextPage**.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of years late, but here is the code I'm using:

```
      Word.Range wrdRng = mWordDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range;
      wrdRng.InsertBreak(ref oSectionBreak);

      Word.Paragraph oPara1 = mWordDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref oMissing);
      oPara1.Range.Text = "Strategies & Performance Metrics";
      oPara1.Range.set_Style(ref styleHeading2);
      oPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
      mWordDoc.Sections[2].PageSetup.Orientation = Word.WdOrientation.wdOrientLandscape;
```

I should have some code for getting the section number I add.

Comment: How and where are you creating `mWordDoc`?